# Why pacman cannot find a package from aur.archlinux.org/packages?

Tags: archlinux, gnome-terminal, pacman-package-manager

I wanna install `gnome-terminal-transparency` package.
Here it is a [link](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnome-terminal-transparency/).
But my `pacman` cannot find anything related to `gnome-terminal-transparency`:

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Manjaro (Arch based). I also cannot use the command "pacman" for AUR. I need to use the command "`sudo pamac install <package>`" to download packages from the AUR.

Answer (score 0):

Pacman does not manage AUR packages. This is by design. [This wiki article contains some description of why](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_User_Repository). If you do not wish to manage your AUR packages in the recommended way (by hand), you must install an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AUR_helpers). The only way to install an AUR helper from the AUR is to do it manually in order to familiarize yourself with the process of installing packages from the AUR so you know what the helper is doing. If I were you, since this seems to be your first time operating an Arch based system given the content of the question, I would STRONGLY, S T R O N G L Y, advise against using a GUI helper like pamac. These handwave away far too much of the AUR install process and can easily brick your system

Answer (score 0):

try `yay -S <package>`. I just did this for nvidia-container-toolkit which is not it pacman repos, but in aur. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nvidia-container-toolkit